# = can not have such operands in this context

Tags: vhdl, operand

Here's the full error: ERROR:HDLParsers:808 - "C:/Users/vROG/Desktop/.../CacheController.vhd" Line 72. = can not have such operands in this context.

I'd understand how to fix this if I was used '+' or '*', but equal sign?

As you can tell, the code isn't nearly being close to completely, but I can't understand why my second nested if isn't working. I've tried turning dirtyBIT to type int, but it still gives me the same error, which leads me to believe that I made a trivial error somewhere.

FIXED (Using user1155120's advice) However how do I resolve the issue with offset and tag?

```
architecture Behavioral of CacheController is

signal tagFROMCPU :  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0) := CPU_addr(15 downto 8);
signal indexFROMCPU: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 downto 0) := CPU_addr(7 downto 5);
signal offsetFROMCPU: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 downto 0) := CPU_addr(4 downto 0);

TYPE STATETYPE IS (state_0, state_1, state_2, state_3);
SIGNAL present_state    : STATETYPE;

--Variables
signal dirtyBIT: std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
signal validBIT: std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);

TYPE tag is array (7 downto 0) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
TYPE offset is array (7 downto 0) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 downto 0);

signal myTag: tag;
signal myOFFSET : offset;
    begin

--STATE MACHINE
process(clk)    
begin
    if (present_state = state_0) then --Start State : Checks for HIT or MISS, PERFORMS HIT OPERATION or MOVES TO STATE_1
        if ((myTag(to_integer(unsigned(indexFROMCPU)) = tagFROMCPU)) then
        --HIT
        else
            present_state <= state_1;
        end if;
    elsIF (present_state = state_1) then --CHECKS DIRTY BIT. IF 0, LOADS DATA, MOVES TO STATE_0 ELSE move to state_2

        if (dirtyBit(to_integer(unsigned(indexFROMCPU))) = '0') then
            present_state <= state_0;
        else
            present_state <= state_2;
        end if;

    elsIF(present_state = state_2) then -- DIRTY BIT IS 1, SAVES DATA, goes back to STATE_1
            present_state <= state_1;
    end if;
end process;


end Behavioral;
```

OLD CODE

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;


entity CacheController is
Port (
        clk         : in  STD_LOGIC;
        CPU_addr    : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
        CPU_WR_RD   : in  STD_LOGIC;
        CPU_CS      : in  STD_LOGIC;

        CPU_RDY     : out STD_LOGIC;

        SDRAM_Addr  : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
        SDRAM_WR_RD : out  STD_LOGIC;
        SDRAM_MSTRB : out  STD_LOGIC;

        MUX1,MUX2   : out STD_LOGIC;

        SRAM_Addr   : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
        SRAM_WEN    : out  STD_LOGIC

);

end CacheController;

architecture Behavioral of CacheController is

signal tagFROMCPU :  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0) := CPU_addr(15 downto 8);
signal indexFROMCPU: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 downto 0) := CPU_addr(7 downto 5);
signal offsetFROMCPU: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 downto 0) := CPU_addr(4 downto 0);

TYPE STATETYPE IS (state_0, state_1, state_2, state_3);
SIGNAL present_state    : STATETYPE;

--Variables to emulate SRAM
TYPE dirtyBIT is array (7 downto 0) of std_logic;
TYPE validBIT is array (7 downto 0) of std_logic;
TYPE tag is array (7 downto 0,7 downto 0) of std_logic;
TYPE offset is array (7 downto 0,4 downto 0) of std_logic;

begin

--STATE MACHINE
process(clk)    
begin
    if (present_state = state_0) then --Start State : Checks for HIT or MISS, PERFORMS HIT OPERATION or MOVES TO STATE_1

    elsIF (present_state = state_1) then --CHECKS DIRTY BIT. IF 0, LOADS DATA, MOVES TO STATE_0 ELSE move to state_2

        if (dirtyBit(to_integer(unsigned(indexFROMCPU))) = '0') then
            present_state <= state_0;
        else
            present_state <= state_2;
        end if;

    elsIF(present_state = state_2) then -- DIRTY BIT IS 1, SAVES DATA, goes back to STATE_1
            present_state <= state_1;
    end if;
end process;


end Behavioral;
```

Comment: The code that you pasted only consists of 64 lines. Which one is supposed to be the offending line number 72?

Comment: This is an XST error. @mkrieger1 - line 52. `dirtyBit` is the name of a  type. Perhaps you want to declare it as a signal object? I'd suspect that will hold true for all four of the `-- Variables` you show as types.

Comment: @user1155120 Is correct. Replacing Dirtybit with any of the --Variables will give the same error. Will try declaring them as signals

Comment: Don't ruined the value of your question/answer to third parties by making it unclear.  Consider rolling your edit back here  and asking another question.  I answered and can't tell what *issue with offset and tag* you're asking about now. Unclear can lead to down votes and closure, accepted answers can block further interest.  You're not asking for debug help now. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). There may be issues suited for different tags or other Stack Exchange sites. Good direct questions get good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operator overload resolution (for the "=" operator) requires a function be declared with a matching signature (types of the left and right inputs and the return type).

```
        if (dirtyBit(to_integer(unsigned(indexFROMCPU))) = '0') then
```

Change the declaration for `dirtyBit`:

```
--Variables to emulate SRAM
-- TYPE dirtyBIT is array (7 downto 0) of std_logic;
signal dirtyBIT: std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
```

And your code analyzes. I'd suggest the other type declaration (`validBIT`, `tag` and `offset`) should be similarly treated.

It looks like there should be an array type where `offset` is used. The type name might be changed to preserve `offset` as a signal name.